# scalaz trying to use Heap , how to override fold function

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a case class: `case class Item(id: Long, rank: Int)` and i want to create a heap of Item objects. I try to create an instance of `Heap[Item]` but i have to override a fold function, i do not know exactly what to do and therefore i am stuck at this point

```
val heap = new Heap[Item] {
      override def fold[B](empty: => B, nonempty: (Int, (Item, Item) => Boolean, Tree[Ranked[Item]]) => B): B = {

      }
    }
```

What do i have to do to make this work so i can use the heap collection ;
Thanks.

Comment: You _have to_ override it but don't know what you want it to do???

Comment: I do not know what fold is for , its the first time i use scalaz i could not even find example code.

Comment: Don't use scalaz then. You don't need it. And don't override functions if you don't know what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be directly calling `new Heap` to begin with.

First, define an implicit `Order` for your `Item`s. For example to order by rank:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

case class Item(id: Long, rank: Int)
object Item {
  implicit val order: Order[Item] = Order.orderBy(_.rank)
}
```

And then create `Heap`s using helper methods from the `Heap` companion object:

```
Heap.Empty[Item]
Heap.singleton(Item(1L, 1))
Heap.fromData(List(Item(10L, 3), Item(20L, 2), Item(30L, 1)))
```